# Fix a RewriteRule - Access an ID at the end of a string separated by a Hyphen

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have an image gallery with over 3 thousand images and still growing. My url to access an image is the following:

```
1.
http://example.com/gallery/image/cloud-blue-plane-hawaii-428459

or 

2.
http://example.com/gallery/image/428459
```

The PHP script is found here:

```
http://example.com/gallery/image.php?image=428459
```

So, I need to write a RewriteRule to access it.

I believe the correct rule for the second url ( `http://example.com/gallery/image/428459`
) is as follow:

```
RewriteRule ^gallery/image/(\d+|[^/]+)/?$ gallery/image.php?image=$1 [L]
```

I’m kind of stock when it’s time to write the rule for the first url ( `http://example.com/gallery/image/cloud-blue-plane-hawaii-428459` )… I have no idea…

Is there a way to make one rule for both url’s?

Comment: Don't use an `or` make the leading part optional. I think `gallery/image/\D*(\d+)/?$` does it for you.

Comment: This solution almost works. If there's a digit in the string, it fails: `http://example.com/gallery/image/cloud-blue-plane-99-hawaii-428459`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```php
^gallery/image/[^/]*?([0-9]+)/?$
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/88azeh/2).

**Explanation**

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  gallery/image/           'gallery/image/'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [^/]*?                   any character except: '/' (0 or more times
                           (matching the least amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [0-9]+                   digits (0-9) (1 or more times (matching
                             the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  /?                       '/' (optional (matching the most amount
                           possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  $                        before an optional \n, and the end of the
                           string
```